# Deploy Module Button

Tags: gwt

how can I enable the 'Deploy Module' - Button in Eclipse 4.2 (Ubuntu/Windows/GWT SDK 2.5).

[image: button]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

according to picture, eclipse seam's not recognize "loginmanager" project as a Web application.

may be Have a look in his properties > facets

Comment: sorry for not being clear enough. the screenshot is taken from the gwt website as an example to show you the button.

Comment: anyway, my answer is still valid ! is your project's icon shows a 'earth' ?

Comment: under properties -> project facets only Java is checked.